# Breaking custom components on multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render a list in react native. The list items should be very simple, at least in theory. It has a header and a body. The header is no problem. It's just a `Text` component. But I do struggle with the body component.

This is how the list item looks like right now:[image]

Below is an illustration on how I would like the list item to look like:

[image]

As you see, the desired result would be to stack all the components in the body next to each other horizontally(flexDirection:'row'), this would require that part of the custom component(se below:"ListItemBodyElement") should break to a new line if it doesn't fit the previous line.

This is the current code(I've left out the code for the header component for brevity):

ParentView:

```
const ListItemBody = props => {
  return <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flexWrap:'wrap',justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>{props.children}</View>;
};
```

The `props.children` contains of x `ListItemBodyElement`:

```
const ListItemBodyElement = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      {props.icon && <props.icon style={styles.icon} name={props.iconName} />}
      <Text style={{...styles.label, ...props.labelStyle}}>{props.label}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired result?
Thanks in advance.
/Arif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering all the elements within a Text component. This should order them sequentially and place oversized content on a new line.

```js
const ListItemBody = props => {
  return <View style={{flexDirection:'row',flexWrap:'wrap',justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>
    <Text>{props.children}</Text>
  </View>;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response @Abe ...it only did half of the job by ordering the components sequentially. The text however don't break  to a new line anymore. It continues horizontally out of screen and breaks only on a new body component.

Comment: Maybe put a fixed width into the styles of the parent View? `width: '100%'` or something

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work still having an overflow.

Comment: @Abe..It was the `View` tags in the `ListItemBodyElement`  that caused the overflow. I replacde the`View` tags with  fragments and it worked: const ListItemBodyElement = `props => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.icon && <props.icon style={styles.icon} name={props.iconName} />}
      <Text style={{...styles.label, ...props.labelStyle}}>{props.label}</Text>
    </>
  );
};`   /Thanks

Comment: Interesting, nice find!

Answer (score 1):

Try set `word-break: break-all` on `Text`.

This should prevent the text overflow, hopefully making it closer to the desired result.

[More about `word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Example:

```
<Text style={{ ...styles.label, ...props.labelStyle, wordBreak: "break-all" }}>
  {props.label}
</Text>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks for your respone but adding wordBreak: "break-all"  didn't change anything.